# SignalR. WebSocket connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

Всем привет. Подключаюсь к SignalR. (Все работает). Но.
В начале появляется следующая ошибка:

*WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:****/newhub?id=gic7TTgRm3kEY7NqJh6y0Q&access_token=eyJhbGciOiJITzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy13cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiS2liZXJpb25Db2RlckBtYWlsLnJ1IiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYMMubWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbS93cy8yMDA4LzA2L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9yb2xlIjoic3VwcGxpZXSiLCJuYmYiOjE1NTcxODA5MTAsImV4cCI6MTU1NzI2NDkxMCwiaXNzIjoiQXV0aFNlcnZlciIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTA1MjMvIn0.o1Q2435lkPmYTngLPMX40k0jGiykGE6Qn9UUDxjvt0o' failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available*

*Error: Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': null*

Также *401 (Unauthorized)* (хотя я отправляю токен)

Спустя примерно секунду:

*Information: Using HubProtocol 'json'.*

Т.е. подключение проходит успешно, но не сразу.
Непонятно одно. Почему появляется ошибка при старте?
Ведь дальше подключение проходит успешно.

Comment: Сейчас угадаю: запрос на соединение отправляется асинхронный, но без указания `await`.

Comment: await я указывал.

Comment: Ошибка появляется именно при добавлении авторизации.